# How to use pd.data_range() with a frequency of X minutes/hours/seconds?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

I need to create a frequent date range with pandas `date_range()`. This works well with `frequency=...` parameter.
But sometimes my code needs these frequent ranges in longer frequencys. for example `4` Hours or `5` minutes instead of one.

How can I do that with `pd.date_range(first_X_datetime, last_X_datetime, freq=frequency)`?

If there is not a more efficient way, my idea would be to create a pd.date_range and then drop the unincluded indices. But how to do that ?
(currently i cant think of a better approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always customize the frequency as you wish instead of only `1 hour` or `1 minute`.

```py
In [237]: pd.date_range(start, end, freq='2h20min')
Out[237]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-01-01 02:20:00',
               '2011-01-01 04:40:00', '2011-01-01 07:00:00',
               '2011-01-01 09:20:00', '2011-01-01 11:40:00',
               '2011-01-01 14:00:00', '2011-01-01 16:20:00',
               '2011-01-01 18:40:00', '2011-01-01 21:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='140T')

In [238]: pd.date_range(start, end, freq='1D10U')
Out[238]: 
DatetimeIndex([       '2011-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-01-02 00:00:00.000010',
               '2011-01-03 00:00:00.000020', '2011-01-04 00:00:00.000030',
               '2011-01-05 00:00:00.000040', '2011-01-06 00:00:00.000050',
               '2011-01-07 00:00:00.000060', '2011-01-08 00:00:00.000070',
               '2011-01-09 00:00:00.000080', '2011-01-10 00:00:00.000090'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='86400000010U')
```

Please check it out here for more information:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html

Comment: thats awesome, do you know how to get it from a frequency start that is always "00 00 00" till 23:59:59?

Something like: starttime `'2011-01-01 5:37:00'` endtime `'2011-01-01 23:59:49'`
But the frequency acts as if it started at `'2011-01-01 00:00:00'`. Is that possible?

Comment: I think you can preprocess the start time and end time (which is quite easy) before you pass it to this function. By default, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: is there a way to do that with multiindex and then multiply by a pattern like intraday-times index (extracted by the first day, starting at midnight)